# Using binarySearch to look for Object in ArrayList

Tags: java, binary-search

I have a problem with searching for an Object in an ArrayList.

This is my code so far:

```
public static int binarySearch( ArrayList list, Object key ) {
    Comparable comp = (Comparable)key;

    int res = -1, min = 0, max = list.size() - 1, pos;
    while( ( min <= max ) && ( res == -1 ) ) {
        pos = (min + max) / 2;
        int comparison = comp.compareTo(pos);
        if( comparison == 0)
            res = pos;
        else if( comparison < 0)
            max = pos - 1;
        else
            min = pos + 1;
    }
    return res;
}
```

And this is my testing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(new String("February"));
    list.add(new String("January"));
    list.add(new String("June"));
    list.add(new String("March"));

    System.out.println(list);

    Object obj = new String("February");

    int index = binarySearch(list, obj);

    System.out.println(obj + " is at index" + index);

}
```

The program always returns -1, which means that it never finds the object it's searching for? Do you see any error? Or am I testing the search incorrectly?

Comment: `new String("February")` is nonsense. Just write `"February"`. There is no use for constructing a `String` by passing another `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing `comp` against `pos` which is like comparing a `Comparable` (in this case, a `String`) with an `Integer`:

```
int comparison = comp.compareTo(pos);
```

You should, instead, retrieve the element in `pos` index in the list and use that element to do the comparison:

```
int comparison = comp.compareTo(list.get(pos));
```

Comment: Of course, that makes sense!

But after the change, I am still receiving -1 even though in this case the index should be 0?

Comment: @theOGloc I just copied and pasted your code with my change and prints *February is at index0*. Changed the key to `"June"` and printed *June is at index2*. Make sure to save the changes, recompile and re-run your tests.

Comment: Yes of course. I realized that I have a custom incomplete ArrayList class which was giving me wrong size of the list. Thanks for the help!